# Converting a Java (or a javascript) file to a 3d model (preferably OBJ)

Tags: java, javascript, model, 3d

Alrighty, so I have some models from this 3d program called techne (for minecraft). I can export 3d models from Techne to .java or .js files

The .js files look somethign like this:

```
var body1 = new Model();
body1.addBox("body1", -8, 20, 0, 16, 16, 23, 0, 30);
body1.setPosition(0, 0, 0);
body1.setRotation(0, 0, 0);
```

and so on and so forth. My question is, how do I convert a .java or .js (or a .tcn [Techne format]) into a .obj file

Here is Techne: http://techne.zeux.me/Techne

Is there any sort of Java 3d model viewer which can open such files, and allow me to export them?

Searches on the interweb have only yielded me info about going from a 3d obj to Java, but not the other way around

A sample .js file: `http://goo.gl/NGDeoE`
A sample .java file: `http://goo.gl/EaqqLm`

Thanks so much! Hope to hear from some one soon :)
~MT

Comment: Note: .tcn is actually a zip file. Try to view it with 7zip or something like that, you will be surprised ^^

Answer (score 0):

OBJ format doesn't make a lot of sense for this kind of data because what you have is a bunch of transformations (coordinates) for a couple of identical objects(cubes) inlined in the source code. OBJ format  doesn't support  multiply repetition of the same geometry(only vertices) so it will have overhead.  So to make proper converter you must first decide what you want to do with this data and it won't be one solution for all cases.  If you want to import this data to the 3d editor like Blender or 3Ds MAX it makes sense to weld all cubes together and remove  invisible sides, make a texture atlas.

OBJ format is really simple and intended to be human readable and with those source files that you shown it won't take a lot of time to write proper exporter on JS or JAVA  tuned for your needs.